# Как открыть сайт в браузере из perl-скрипта?

Tags: perl

Как можно открыть сайт из perl-скрипта?

Answer (score 1):

Установить модуль [Browser::Open](https://metacpan.org/pod/Browser::Open):

```
cpan install Browser::Open
```

Попробовать запустить:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Browser::Open qw( open_browser );

my $url = 'https://ru.stackoverflow.com/';
open_browser($url);
```

Должен (обязан) запуститься ваш дефолтный браузер.